Qualtrics JavaScript: Randomizing and Displaying One Choice from Multiple Subsets in a Qualtrics Rank Order Question
I’m working on a Rank Order question in Qualtrics and need help achieving a specific design using JavaScript. Here’s what I want to do:
Problem:
I have three different categories of choices:
A (A1, A2, ...)
B (B1, B2, ….)
C (C1, C2 ...)
Each category has 4 choices. What I need to do is randomly select and display one option from each category (so 3 total), shuffle the order in which they appear, and hide the rest. I also need to ensure the Rank Order drag-and-drop functionality still works after the randomization.
What I’ve Tried:
I’ve written a JavaScript code to randomly pick one choice from each category and hide the rest, but I’m facing issues with reinitializing the Rank Order functionality.
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {

    // Define the blocks with their choices
    var groupAChoices = [
        "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"
    ];

    var groupBChoices = [
        "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"
    ];

    var groupCChoices = [
        "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"
    ];

    // Randomly pick one option from each group
    var groupAPick = groupAChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * groupAChoices.length)];
    var groupBPick = groupBChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * groupBChoices.length)];
    var groupCPick = groupCChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * groupCChoices.length)];

    // Combine the selected choices into an array
    var selectedChoices = [groupAPick, groupBPick, groupCPick];

    // Randomize the order of the selected choices
    for (let i = selectedChoices.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [selectedChoices[i], selectedChoices[j]] = [selectedChoices[j], selectedChoices[i]];
    }

    // Display the randomized choices
    this.getChoiceContainer().innerHTML = "<ul>" + selectedChoices.map(choice => "<li>" + choice + "</li>").join('') + "</ul>";
});

With the code, the survey preview displays the random choices but the drag and drop functions is not available anymore after running the code. I couldn't find any fix for this problem. Can anyone help me?
